# Android - glide jar issue when making signed apk

Tags: android, eclipse, android-glide

I am getting following error when making signed apk,
please help me to resolve this.
I have used Glide jar in the app.

[2017-04-29 17:22:42 - myApp] Warning: com.bumptech.glide.manager.SupportRequestManagerFragment: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment getParentFragment()' in class com.bumptech.glide.manager.SupportRequestManagerFragment

[2017-04-29 17:22:42 - myApp] Warning: com.bumptech.glide.manager.SupportRequestManagerFragment: can't find referenced method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity getActivity()' in class com.bumptech.glide.manager.SupportRequestManagerFragment

[2017-04-29 17:22:42 - myApp] Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.

[2017-04-29 17:22:42 - myApp]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.

[2017-04-29 17:22:42 - myApp]          You may need to recompile them and try again.

[2017-04-29 17:22:42 - myApp]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option

[2017-04-29 17:22:42 - myApp]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.

[2017-04-29 17:22:42 - myApp] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

[2017-04-29 17:22:42 - myApp]     at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)

[2017-04-29 17:22:42 - myApp]     at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)

[2017-04-29 17:22:42 - myApp]     at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)

[2017-04-29 17:22:42 - myApp]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)

Answer (score 0):

You have this error because you are using `proGuard` in your relase apk

You may need to include the following lines in your `proguard.cfg` / `proguard.pro`

```
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public enum 
com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}

# for DexGuard only
-keepresourcexmlelements manifest/application/meta-data@value=GlideModule
```

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur if you have the wrong path to 'proguard.cfg' in your project.properties.
Make sure you declare the right path, example is below

```
    proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard.cfg
```

If the error still persists, do the following for all the packages throwing the error/warning in your proguard.cfg file

```
    -dontwarn com.google.code.**
    -dontwarn oauth.signpost.**
    -dontwarn twitter4j.**
```

Working proguard.cfg file example:

```
    -optimizationpasses 5
    -dontusemixedcaseclassnames
    -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
    -dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
    -dontpreverify
    -dontshrink
    -verbose

    -injars bin/classes
    -injars libs
    -outjars bin/classes-processed.jar

    -libraryjars C:/glassfish3/jdk7/jre/lib/rt.jar 
    -libraryjars C:/glassfish3/jdk7/lib/tools.jar

    -dontwarn org.apache.**
    -dontwarn org.slf4j.**
    -dontwarn org.json.*
    -dontwarn org.mortbay.**
    -dontwarn org.apache.log4j.**
    -dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
    -dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
    -dontwarn org.apache.commons.codec.binary.**
    -dontwarn javax.xml.**
    -dontwarn javax.management.**
    -dontwarn java.lang.management.**
    -dontwarn android.support.**
    -dontwarn com.google.code.**
    -dontwarn oauth.signpost.**
    -dontwarn twitter4j.**

    -optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

    -keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
    -keep public class * extends android.app.Application
    -keep public class * extends android.app.Service
    -keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
    -keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
    -keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
    -keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
    -keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService
    -keep public class com.google.code.linkedinapi.**

    -keep class javax.**  { *; }
    -keep class org.**  { *; }
    -keep class twitter4j.**  { *; }
    -keep class java.lang.management.**  { *; }
    -keep class com.google.code.**  { *; }
    -keep class oauth.signpost.**  { *; }

    -keepclassmembers public class         com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.LinkedInApiXppClient {
 public <init>(java.lang.String, java.lang.String);
    }

    -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
native <methods>;
    }

    -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    }

    -keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
        public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
            }

    -keepclassmembers enum * {
        public static **[] values();
        public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
    }

    -keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
      public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
```

}